# Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS unbearably slow after entering passphrase for WiFi

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, performance, non-pae

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS on an (quite old) IBM ThinkPad T40.

Connecting to the internet using LAN works perfectly fine, but as soon as I "Enable Wireless" in the Network Manager, choose a (WPA2-encrypted) network, enter a password (doesn't matter whether it is correct or not) and hit the "Connect" button, the laptop becomes unbearably slow and unusable. The problem persists after a reboot.

The laptop can be made reusable by deleting Network Managers's configuration file using Ubuntu's Recovery Mode: `root@laptop:~# rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NameOfNetworkIWantToConnectTo`.

Here are some details about my wifi adapter.

```
me@laptop:~$ lspci | grep Wireless
02:02.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR5211 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5001X 802.11ab] (rev 01)

me@laptop:~$ rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Unblocking `phy0` using `sudo rfkill unblock 1` didn't help (edited on 2016-07-14).

Googling has brought me to some hypotheses on the problem but not yet to a solution:

- The **driver** might be buggy
- There might be an issue with the **kernel** or in the interaction of the driver and the kernel: when the OS froze, I was able to switch to the console and something like "task wpa_supplicant blocked for more than 120 seconds" appeared on screen ⇒ kernel panic?
- **`wpa_supplicant`** might be the cause of the problem
- There was one post on deactivating the **hardware encryption** of the wireless adapter. But it was for another device and I didn't know how to adapt that for my case.
- As it's an old device with an old processor (Intel Pentium M), the installation of Ubuntu was made using the **forcepae** option. Might this cause the problem?

  - Installation crashed for later versions of Ubuntu (USB drive was deactivated during installation which consequently led to reading errors)

Previously, installing all updates led to a crashed dependency stack because of some kernel-related packages. Therefore, I've installed all updates except for those affecting the kernel.

Do you have any ideas on how I could solve the problem? If yes, I'd kindly ask you to share them with me. ^-^

Best wishes

Comment: I have a ThinkPad T40 running Ubuntu 12.04 as well, and I installed 32 bit Linux no problem without the **forcepae** flag. I wonder if you could do the same? Also (you probably did) but did you unblock the block on your net adapter? `sudo rfkill unblock phy0`

Comment: I also ran a dist-upgrade which broke most things, and had to reinstall. I wouldn't suggest it (it tried pushing me over to a PAE-only kernel version, I think?) and will also add that I have only tried my T40 on a friend's WEP connection so I can't necessarily speak for WPA. I'm here to experiment with/for you though, since it's not my main machine. No worries if I break it a couple times, I can always fix it! :D

Comment: Hi @PSmith thank you very much for your answer! I actually haven't tried using `sudo rfkill unblock 1` yet but unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Comment: Retrying a clean install without **forcepae** resulted in `ERROR: PAE is disabled on this Pentium M` and `This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU: pae`, so it probably is needed :D  By the way very cool that you've got a T40 and are willing to help me. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I've found another router in my house, have set up a non-encrypted and a WPA-encrypted wifi, have connected to it and am experiencing the same problem ⇒ problem appears to be independent of the network and encryption of the network I'm trying to connect to.